# Use R to mimic "clicking" on a file to download it

Tags: r, web-scraping, httr, rselenium

I would like R to automatically download an excel file about Oil and Gas rigs from [this page](https://rigcount.bakerhughes.com/na-rig-count). The file is downloaded by clicking on "*North America Rotary Rig Count Pivot Table (Feb 2011 - Current)*" (second option) but I cannot seem to find a way to do this in R.

Any clues? Thanks!

**Note:** Unfortunately, using download.file() does not seem to work. I get a message when trying to open the file in MS Excel that the extension is incorrect or the file is corrupt. I also get this error in R when using `readxl::read_excel()`: *Error: Evaluation error: error -103 with zipfile in unzGetCurrentFileInfo*

Comment: You tagged [tag:rselenium], have you tried the [`RSelenium`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/) package? Often the need for browser-emulation in Selenium is not strictly required, have you tried [`rvest`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/)?

Comment: Some initial testing tells me that `rvest` would be sufficient, I suggest you look at https://rvest.tidyverse.org/ for how best to learn/use `rvest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some libs to help
You actually will need only `dplyr`, `purrr`, stringr, and `xml2`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rvest'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     pluck
#> The following object is masked from 'package:readr':
#> 
#>     guess_encoding
library(htmltab)
library(xml2)
library(readxl)
```

I like to do it this way because some sites use partial links.

```r
base <- "https://rigcount.bakerhughes.com"
url <- paste0(base, "/na-rig-count")

# find links
url_html <- xml2::read_html(url)
url_html %>% 
  html_nodes("a") %>% 
  html_attrs() %>% 
  bind_rows() -> url_tbl
```

Check href content, find some pattern you are interested in.
You may use `inspect` on your browser too, it is truly helpful.

```r
url_tbl %>% 
  count(href)
#> # A tibble: 22 x 2
#>    href                                                                        n
#>    <chr>                                                                   <int>
#>  1 /                                                                           1
#>  2 /email-alerts                                                               1
#>  3 /intl-rig-count                                                             1
#>  4 /na-rig-count                                                               1
#>  5 /rig-count-faqs                                                             1
#>  6 /rig-count-overview                                                         2
#>  7 #main-menu                                                                  1
#>  8 https://itunes.apple.com/app/baker-hughes-rig-counts/id393570114?mt=8       1
#>  9 https://rigcount.bakerhughes.com/static-files/4ab04723-b638-4310-afd9-…     1
#> 10 https://rigcount.bakerhughes.com/static-files/4b92b553-a48d-43a3-b4d9-…     1
#> # … with 12 more rows
```

Perhaps, I notice that *static-files* may be a good pattern to `href` but then I found a better one, in `type`.

```r
url_tbl %>% 
  filter(str_detect(type, "ms-excel")) -> url_xlsx
```

build our list (remember to avoid some noise as an extra dot, spaces, and special characters)
I hope someone proposes a better way to avoid those things

```r
myFiles <- pull(url_xlsx, "href")
names <- pull(url_xlsx, "title")
names(myFiles) <- paste0(
    str_replace_all(names, "[\\.\\-\\ ]", "_"), 
    str_extract(names, ".\\w+$")
)

# download data
myFiles %>% 
  imap(
    ~ download.file(
      url = .x, 
      destfile = .y,
      method="curl", # might be not necessary 
      extra="-k"
    )
  )
#> $`north_america_rotary_rig_count_jan_2000_-_current.xlsb`
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> $`north_american_rotary_rig_count_pivot_table_feb_2011_-_current.xlsb`
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> $`U.S.  Monthly Averages by State 1992-2016.xls`
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> $`North America Rotary Rig Counts through 2016.xls`
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> $`U.S. Annual Averages by State 1987-2016.xls`
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> $Workover_9.xls
#> [1] 0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Now you may see your files.

```r
names(myFiles) %>%
    map(
        readxlsb:read_xlsb
    ) -> myData
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, I run here into the same problem as just using download.file(). Although the file is downloaded, it is unreadable both by MS Excel and by R. Any idea how I can work around that?

Comment: @Ham the way I did I was able to read with `readxl` on R and with LibreOffice. I don't use MSofficer.
Actually, I didn't know that exists a format called `*.xlsb`  but it was also opened. Maybe you may avoid the spaces, dot, and orders special character. 
`paste0(str_replace_all(a, "[\\.\\-\\ ]", "_"), str_extract(a, ".\\w+$"))` I'll update on answer

Comment: I made two changes to your code that made it work: I added `method="curl", extra="-k"` to `download.file()`. This solved the problem with the file showing as corrupt. I also used `readxlsb:read_xlsb()` to read the file into R, which appears to be the only way R would read this format. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You're welcome. If you can you'd evaluate the response voting up? 
I'll add those modifications.